# Corporate Credit Risk Modeling Books

Tags: machine-learning, credit-risk, credit, credit-ratings

Can anybody refer me to a good *corporate* credit risk modeling book? I'm looking for something more advanced than what's in Hull's very good risk management book. There seems to be many excellent credit risk modeling books out there, but most of them appear to be for sell-side quants. I'm particularly interested in measuring default risk, CDS spreads, and letter ratings, but would like to learn more about the topic generally.

Comment: Take a look at Terry Benzschawel.  _Credit Risk Modelling: Facts, Theory, and Applications_ Risk Books (2012) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HS45W8Q and https://www.amazon.com/dp/B078SY21XZ

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks!

Comment: You may also like his _Machine Learning: Origins, Developments and Implications_ https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CT48FPZF

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks! I'll check that one out too.